# Prepare is not called after validation fail

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2

I have a jsp page displaying a form for an exam and a list of questions. When the user wants to edit one of the questions but hasn't selected one, the validation in the question action fails and we stay on the exam jsp.

In order to repopulate the exam.jsp. the `ExamAction`(`ActionSupport`) implements `Preparable` and all parameters are set there.

**But when debugging, I found out that `prepare()` is never called after validation.**
However, when a other method of `ExamAction`is called, so is `prepare()`. How come it is merely not working afert validation?

I am using the `defaultStack`, which I have read is not supposed to be the problem.

If you need any further information or code, please let me know.

---

**EDIT**

Here is my `ExamAction`

(the `BaseAction` extends `ActionSupport`and implements `SessionAware`)

```
public class ExamAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable {


/** class variables */


@Override
public void prepare() {

    questionTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    QuestionType[] allTypes = QuestionType.values();
    for (QuestionType questionType : allTypes) {
        questionTypes.add(questionType.toString());
    }

    long id = 0l;
    if (examId != null) {
        id = examId;
    } else if (question != null) {
        id = question.getExam().getId();
    } else {
        Exam currentExam = (Exam) getSession().get("exam");
        if (currentExam != null) {
            id = currentExam.getId();
        }
    }
    if (id != 0) {
        exam = examService.loadExam(id);
        getSession().put("exam", exam);
        questionList = exam.getQuestions();
        getSession().remove("question");
        participantList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (ExamKey examKey : exam.getExamKeys()) {
            participantList.add(examKey.getUser());
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Displays the selected/current exam in the exam form and load it's
 * questions.
 * 
 * @return the result string.
 */
public String load() {
    long id = 0l;
    if (examId != null) {
        id = examId;
    } else if (question != null) {
        id = question.getExam().getId();
    } else {
        Exam currentExam = (Exam) getSession().get("exam");
        if (currentExam != null) {
            id = currentExam.getId();
        }
    }
    if (id != 0) {
    exam = examService.loadExam(id);
    getSession().put("exam", exam);
    questionList = exam.getQuestions();
    getSession().remove("question");
        participantList = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (ExamKey examKey : exam.getExamKeys()) {
        participantList.add(examKey.getUser());
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}


@Override
public void validate() {
    // If the exam is not set, the exam ID has to be set.
    if (exam == null && examId == null) {
        exam = (Exam) getSession().get("exam");
        if (exam != null) {
            questionList = exam.getQuestions();
        } else {
            if (question == null) {
                addActionError(getText("msg.selectExam"));
            }
        }
    }
}

/** all getters and setters*/

}
```

struts.xml:

```
<action name="ShowExam" class="de.nak.cars.action.ExamAction"
        method="load">
    <result type="tiles">examForm</result>
</action>

<!-- Loads a existing question and shows it in the question form. -->
<action name="EditQuestion" class="de.nak.cars.action.QuestionAction"
        method="load">
    <result type="tiles">questionForm</result>
    <result type="tiles" name="input">examForm</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Show your action configuration

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: I'm sorry, then I don't know what you mean. The struts.xml?

Comment: yes only the action part, with input and success results

Comment: You are not executing any action on `input` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare()` method is called BEFORE validation so the `validate()` method cannot be the problem

For more info look at [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html) page

Comment: But `validate()` is in QuestionAction and `prepare()`is in ExamAction. I would think, that when validation fails, we "return" to the ExamAction and therefore `prepare()`is called... or do I need to populate all variables in the `prepare()`of the QuestionAction?

Comment: If you redirect to an action that uses a method in a different action class then the prepare method in that class will be called by the prepare interceptor when the action object is created as long as you are using the default interceptor stack or you have specified prepare interceptor in your custom stack. Action classes are different from servlets and get recreated on each request and every time they do their prepare method is called. Short answer, yes you can populate your form in prepare()

Comment: I have now changed the `prepare()`of my QuestionAction and now, for an validation-fail it works!

However, now the questionId that is to be edited is not passed from the jsp to the QuestionAction anymore. The variable questionID is always null (and therefore the validation fails again)

How can I avoid that?

Comment: You have to pass it as a parameter in the url. Otherwise the value will be lost. The html element should have a name that matches the variable name on your action class. You will also have to create getters and setters

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your `ExamAction` you are calling an `EditAction` (or something like that).

Then the `prepare()` (if exists) and the `validation()` (if exists) are executed on the target action (`EditAction`). If the validation fails, you will render the previous JSP (examForm) without being passed by the previous Action (`ExamAction`).

You need to reconfigure the `input` result to return a `redirectAction` to `ExamAction`, instead of a JSP directly.

However, during the `redirectAction`, Action Messages / Errors and Field Errors are lost, because of the new Request being created. Then you can put them in session, or use the `MessageStore` Interceptor (not part of the defaultStack... but first try without, then when everything works open that "new chapter" :)